# Taylor series $(x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Complete the Maclaurin polynomial of degree three for $(x+1)^{1/3}$.

I have completed the first two derivatives of this function and thus have coefficients but am not certain how to put them into the polynomial form.

Thank you!

Comment: What are the first two derivatives that you computed?

Comment: Could you show your first coefficients ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the first three derivatives correct, then the polynomial is
$$
f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3
$$
where $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/3}$.

If you know the general binomial theorem, you have
$$
(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k
$$
where the convergence is for $|x|<1$, if $\alpha$ is not a positive integer. The binomial coefficient is defined as
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}.
$$
So you can check your answer against this general formula.

Comment: This is a "jump the gun" answer.  Perhaps one computes a few terms using derivatives first.  Then, later, generalizes to a "general binomial theorem".

Comment: @GEdgar *If* you know the general binomial theorem. This can be used for checking the answer computed with derivatives.

Comment: To a solution simply verify here: http://um.mendelu.cz/maw-html/menu.php?lang=cs&form=

Comment: It is a good idea to remember the general binomial theorem for this kind of applications.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(0)=(x+1)^{\frac13}$$
Taylor/Maclaurian says that:
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+...$$
$$f(0)=(0+1)^{\frac13}=1$$
$$f'(0)=\frac13(0+1)^{\frac13-1}=\frac13$$
$$f''(0)=\frac13\left(\frac{1}3-1\right)(0+1)^{\frac13-2}=\frac13\left(\frac{1}3-1\right)$$
$$f'''(0)=\frac13\left(\frac{1}3-1\right)\left(\frac{1}3-2\right)(0+1)^{\frac13-3}=\frac13\left(\frac{1}3-1\right)\left(\frac{1}3-2\right)$$
Now, :
$$f(x)=1+\frac13\frac{x}{1!}+\frac13\left(\frac{1}3-1\right)\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac13\left(\frac{1}3-1\right)\left(\frac{1}3-2\right)\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
The general form to which is:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac13(\frac13-1)\dots(\frac13-k+1)}{k!}x^k$$